# CodeIgniter include js,css files from application returns 403 forbidden

Tags: apache, codeigniter, mamp

I am having a problem loading a javascript or css or any other file from inside the application/modules directory.

I am using MAMP and CodeIgniter with HMVC and trying to have a js and css folders inside a module folder. Then when I am calling the controller methods I am also loading the asset files.

I have other sites that are working in that way. The structures are the same and the CodeIgniter versions are the same. Basically I have copied the previous website and started from there.

But it always returns 403 forbidden.

What I did but still nothing changes:

1. the whole site directory is writable and readable.
2. I can create and read new files from PHP to that dir
3. I have htaccess file which I tried to remove or change
4. Reinstalled MAMP
5. Tried to open a simple html file
6. The MAMP user and group has full access to the dir
7. I tried to run the website on another server

The apache log says "[Tue May 22 17:24:30 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] client denied by server configuration"

Here is the .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

At the same time everything is fine with the other site.

I have spent many hours so far and I am stuck.

Any thoughts or suggestions are appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: Is there an `.htaccess` file in either `application/` or `application/modules/`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

CodeIgniter comes with a .htaccess in the `/application` directory which contains

```
Deny from all
```

You'll need to remove this file or change it's ruleset to access js/css files etc from anywhere inside `application/*`

It is however largely inadvisable to allow access entirely to the application, it's perhaps best to modify this .htaccess file to allow access to `application/modules/*/css|js/`

Comment: Many thanks, Ben!

I see the file and will edit it. Strangely, how I do not have it on the other websites, but anyway now it is working :)

Comment: how to do this?